# Не переводит string в integer. "Ошибка времени выполнения"

Tags: pascal

Есть код (Не Delphi), который разбивает слова из строки на перменные:

---

input.txt

```
Dima M 182
Katya F 167
Petr M 165
Andrey M 177
Ira F 179
```

---

Код pascal:

```
...
var i:integer; 
s: array [1..n] of string;
position:byte;

Begin
  assign(input,'input.txt'); 
  reset(input);
  for i:=1 to n do
  begin
    readln(input,s[i]);

    //Строка "Dima M 182"

    //Достать имя из строки
    position := Pos(' ', s[i]); //Позиция первого пробела
    person[i].name:=copy(s[i], 0, position-1); //Вставить слово до первого пробела в переменную
    delete(s[i], 1, position); //Удалить первое слово и первый пробел

    //Осталось "M 182"

    //Достать пол из строки
    position := Pos(' ', s[i]); //Позиция второго пробела 
    person[i].sex:=copy(s[i], 0, position-1); //Вставить слово между первым и вторым пробелами в переменную
    delete(s[i], 1, position); //Удалить второе слово и второй пробел

    //Осталось "182"

    //Достать рост из строки
    person[i].height:=StrToInt(s[i]);
    writeln(person[i].height);
  end;
end.
```

---

Ожидается, что код:

```
person[i].height:=StrToInt(s[i]);
```

Переведет "s[i]" из строки в число, чтобы с "person[i].height" можно было проводить вычисления, но вместо этого компилятор пишет:

```
Ошибка времени выполнения: System.FormatException: Входная строка имела неверный формат.
```

Comment: Убери лишний код и сформулируй вопрос плиз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверь под отладчиком или выведи на экран как-то что ты пытаешься перевести в число в строке `person[i].height:=StrToInt(s[i]);`. Что именно остается в `s[i]` на этот момент. Как увидишь - сразу поймешь в чем проблема.

Comment: Проверил пошагово и выяснил почему у меня появляется эта ошибка. Строк у меня 5, а итерация в цикле 8, поэтому на 6-ой итерации появляется ошибка.